# How to delete a filtered Data Extension?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

When selecting the filtered Data Extension and clicking the "**Delete**" button, the prompt appears and asks `Are you sure you want to delete____?`. When selecting "**Delete**" the following error appears and the filtered Data Extension remains in the list.

```
Error: Not all items were deleted.
```

Comment: i have the same problem. Did you already solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It is to do with the manage policies on the filtered data extension. It appears that by default, when you create a filtered data extension, the checkbox is unchecked ‘Allow users to delete this Data Extension’. Therefore, you have to tick it and then you can delete it.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the permissions. You might need to get in touch with you account admin and ask them to provide you all the permissions related to DE, Filters and Activities.